# Representing a project on top of framework in UML diagram

Tags: laravel, uml, software-design

I have a project I aim to build by laravel framework, but I need to draw the analysis of the project , including the UML diagram, the laravel framework comes with its classes that operates the project (autoloaders and service providers), but my work will be focused on the customizable area of the laravel framework , thus, making a model, middleware, controller, migration.

So how do I clarify in the UML that the shown classes are built on top of laravel framework, by extending laravel classes, without mentioning the whole UML analysis of the framework?

Comment: In UML diagram or in any other diagram like ERD, DMD etc. one don’t need to mention models/classes which are in framework. These diagrams are  irrespective of the framework being used and always reside on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Model the Laravel classes. Only specify the class names, not attributes/operations. Put them in a package called 'Laravel'. Then model your own classes and use generalization relationships to the Laravel classes.
2. Define a stereotype for each Laravel class you use, e.g. ≪BusServiceProvider≫ and apply these stereotypes to your classes.

I would prefer option 1. I usually show these classes using a special background color.